# need to get next Task after the one in the URL

Tags: laravel, loops, laravel-5, foreach

this for each gave me task where task slug is the same as URL now I need to get the first task after  this one so I make redirect link later

```
@foreach ($Tasks as $Task)
   @if (  $Task->slug == Request::segment(5) )
      <h2> {{ $Task->task_name }} </h2>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

I need to get the task how is after the one in URL from foreach

Comment: You should provide example data and URL. What's the content of $Tasks? How does a URL in question look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I hope this will help you

```
@php
    $i = 0
@endphp
@foreach ($Tasks as $Task)
    @if ($i > 0)
        // write your first task logic here
    @endif
    @if (  $Task->slug == Request::segment(5) )
        <h2> {{ $Task->task_name }} </h2>
        @php
            $i = $i + 1
        @endphp
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: it return same value as url i need to get next value after url

Comment: i have updated the code. Please check if it is working.

Comment: Now, Working, I need to get the task that come  after the one in url (  $Task->slug == Request::segment(5)  i changed                                                                        if ($i > 0)
        // write your first task logic here
    endif                                                                                                                      and put it before end of foreach but it get the same value as URL

Comment: Not Working My friend sorry i write it wrong in last comment

Comment: Same as first i need to get The task that is after the one in url can i use for

Comment: please message me in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183719/lokesh-room room

Answer (score 0):

Would Laravel's pagination give you the features you need more easily?

In your controller:

```
$tasks = Task::where('slug', request()->segment(5))->paginate();
```

You can the use the following in your blade:

```
<?php

$tasks->nextPageUrl()

?>
```

Comment: i get this error Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::segment() should not be called statically
 When i try to $tasks = Task::where('slug', Request::segment(5))->paginate();

 in controller

Comment: Oh yes. Edited.

Comment: please come here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183719/lokesh-room